# pandas add column using map based on two variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this :
[image]

what I want to do is to add a column based on two variables loyalty and new

I create a column based on dow and it is mean of waiting on each day of the week I did it like so:

```
dow_waiting = qdata.groupby('dow').agg('mean')['waiting']
qdata['dow_waiting'] = qdata.dow.map(dow_waiting)
```

I want to do the same for loyalty and new columns. if loyalty is 0 and new is 0 get mean of waiting for this situation and paste it in a new column loyalty_waiting and...
how can I do this using map function

Comment: Can you share the expected output ?

Comment: Just a side note, by qdata.groupby('dow').agg('mean')['waiting'] you compute the mean of all fields to just throw away everything except for the mean of waiting. You can make it more efficient by using qdata.groupby('dow').agg({'waiting': 'mean'})

Comment: @AlexandreB. what I want is getting all rows that have loyalty and new 0 and calculate the mean of waiting for those rows and write it in a new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with merge.

```
data= {'loyalty': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
 'new': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
 'waiting': [17, 30, 43, 37, 10, 11, 30, 24, 25, 39, 34, 0, 11, 29, 12, 0, 12, 42, 3, 1, 9, 37, 32, 25, 17, 43, 17, 22, 3, 0, 9, 45, 24, 16, 22, 7, 12, 7, 36, 49, 34, 45, 12, 9, 7, 26, 22, 4, 24, 27]
}

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
# create the sums on loyalty and new
sums=df.groupby(['loyalty', 'new']).mean()
# join them with your original data frame
df.merge(sums, left_on=['loyalty', 'new'], right_index=True)
```

This yileds:

```
    loyalty  new  waiting_x  waiting_y
0         1    0         17  16.666667
1         1    0         30  16.666667
4         1    0         10  16.666667
8         1    0         25  16.666667
14        1    0         12  16.666667
16        1    0         12  16.666667
19        1    0          1  16.666667
27        1    0         22  16.666667
29        1    0          0  16.666667
34        1    0         22  16.666667
35        1    0          7  16.666667
41        1    0         45  16.666667
42        1    0         12  16.666667
43        1    0          9  16.666667
45        1    0         26  16.666667
2         0    0         43  23.857143
6         0    0         30  23.857143
9         0    0         39  23.857143
12        0    0         11  23.857143
18        0    0          3  23.857143
40        0    0         34  23.857143
44        0    0          7  23.857143
3         1    1         37  18.800000
5         1    1         11  18.800000
10        1    1         34  18.800000
11        1    1          0  18.800000
13        1    1         29  18.800000
15        1    1          0  18.800000
22        1    1         32  18.800000
24        1    1         17  18.800000
28        1    1          3  18.800000
30        1    1          9  18.800000
32        1    1         24  18.800000
38        1    1         36  18.800000
46        1    1         22  18.800000
47        1    1          4  18.800000
48        1    1         24  18.800000
7         0    1         24  27.153846
17        0    1         42  27.153846
20        0    1          9  27.153846
21        0    1         37  27.153846
23        0    1         25  27.153846
25        0    1         43  27.153846
26        0    1         17  27.153846
31        0    1         45  27.153846
33        0    1         16  27.153846
36        0    1         12  27.153846
37        0    1          7  27.153846
39        0    1         49  27.153846
49        0    1         27  27.153846
```

Comment: I want to calculate the mean of them not writing them in a new coloumn

Comment: You mean the mean should be the same for all columns where loyalty and new are zero? is that right?

Comment: yes I want the mean of them . not only for loyalty 0 new 0 but for loyalty 1 new 0 and loyalty 0 new 1

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, wait a minute

Comment: I changed the code. Of course you could have done it as described in four steps, but if you don't just have bools but also other variables, the number of steps gets unconfortably large soon, so I change the solution to use merge instead.